# Attempt to de-reference a null object - Error in sorting list

Tags: class, list, null-pointer, null, split

I am getting subject line - error while I try to execute below apex code snippet

**Apex Code Snippet**

```
 for(Integer index = 0; index < surveyInstanceList.size(); index++) {
    Survey_Question_vod__c  sq = surveyInstanceList[index];
    if(sq.text_vod__c!=null) {
        If(Integer.valueof(sq.text_vod__c.split(' ')[1].left(1)) == count) {
            surveyInstanceListsorted.add(sq);  // This line throws error.
            count++;
        } else {
            // -- will step back one to process record that just moved in
            surveyInstanceList.add(surveyInstanceList.remove(index--));
               }
                             }
            }
```

Comment: please add lines where you're initializing surveyInstanceListsorted and surveyInstanceList

Comment: for ex. if `surveyInstanceList` contains only 1 record and 1st for loop iteration it executes else part then what will happen `.remove(index--)` beacuse this time your index will be `-1`

Comment: @Ratan you'd get a index out of bounds exception if that were the case. But you won't actually hit -1, because it's a postfix operator and the loop increment will ensure it will be at least 0.

Comment: @sfdcfox so it if my index is 0 and If I use index--, It will take at least 0 not -1 ? interesting never looked into..

Comment: @Ratan yes, because index 0 will be removed, then there variable index will update to -1, and then the index++ will execute immediately afterwards, so it will again be 0.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks got it.  I think need to look into the flow how it works for more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the line that is throwing the error:

> `surveyInstanceListsorted.add(sq);  // This line throws error.`

The most likely scenario is that ahead of this block of code which you're showing us you did not initialize this `List<Survey_Question_vod__c>` and you're trying to add an item to `null`:

```
surveyInstanceListsorted = new List<Survey_Question_vod__c>();
```